# Is there any way to connect asp.net and powershell on windows 2008 server?

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I want to execute some powershell commands on a remote windows 2008 machine. Right now i am using psexec to run the powershell from c# asp.net application. I would like to know is there any way to execute powershell commands without using a third party tool like psexec?

Thanks,

dijo

Answer (score 1):

There is, using the

```
System.Management.Automation
```

class library and Runspaces. See [this MSDN article about creating Runspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), here's an example from it in C#:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
powershell.AddCommand("Get-Process").AddArgument("wmi*");

foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1}", result.Members["ProcessName"].Value, result.Members["Id"].Value);
}

runspace.Close();
```

Using WS-Management [this can also be done for a remote host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706560%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I created a web application to execute powershell scripts - it might help you - http://psadmin.codeplex.com